# NodeJS and MYSQL Issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

My code is supposed to retrieve the "DropsRemaining" for a user ID (which it does successfully) and then -1 from the number it retrieves. When retreiving the data it returns this string "[ RowDataPacket { DropsRemaining: 5 } }" however the end of the code does not -1 from the DropsRemaining it instead sets the DropsRemaining to -1. If anyone can help fix this I'd really appreciate it.

```js
var sql = "SELECT DropsRemaining FROM UserData WHERE DiscordID LIKE " + message.author.id;

var DropCount = [];
connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
 if (!err)
  setValue(result);
 else
  console.log("No Information For That User Found");
});

function setValue(value) {
 DropCount = value;
 console.log(DropCount);
};
//Remove drop from user
 DropCount = DropCount - 1;
var sql = "UPDATE UserData SET DropsRemaining = " + DropCount + " WHERE DiscordID = " + message.author.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the order you write your Javascript code is not exactly how it is performed in the end.

When you call the `connection.query()` function, the next line of code does not necessarily already have the result of that function.

I would recommend you to have a look on this [book series](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS), they have really good explanations about those characteristics.

Probably the following code will output the expected response. Notice that I nested the code, therefore I can control the flow properly.

```
    var sql = "SELECT DropsRemaining FROM UserData WHERE DiscordID LIKE " + message.author.id;

    // Get the DropsRemaining
    connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            // No errors in the query, decrement the Drops
            decrementDrop(result);
        } else {
          console.log("No Information For That User Found");
        }
    });

    function decrementDrop(dropsAvailable) {
        var dropsRemaining = dropsAvailable - 1;
        var updateSql = "UPDATE UserData SET DropsRemaining = " + dropsRemaining + " WHERE DiscordID = " + message.author.id;

        // Update the DropsRemaining column to the dropsRemaining, i.e., decrement the DropsRemaining column value
        connection.query(updateSql, function (err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("DiscordID = " + message.author.id +" has " + dropsRemaining + " drops remaining")
            } else {
                console.log("Error!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It just gives me an error later in my code “unexpected });”

Comment: I updated the answer, a curly bracket was missing to close the function decrementDrop, can you try again?